# Python & PostgreSql: Insert Value Into Column In Table

Tags: python, database, postgresql, function, insert

I have the following PostgreSql table:

[image]

I want to insert a string value of 3 into the first row under the diagnosis column.  I'm trying to follow some general INSERT code from the postgresql documentation.  Below is my trial code that is **not** working.

```
diagnosis = 3; 

pip install config

# insert 

import psycopg2
from config import config


def insert_diagnosis(diagnosis):
    """ insert a new diagnosis prediction into the eyeballtables table """
    sql = """INSERT INTO eyeballtables(diagnosis)
             VALUES(%s) RETURNING vendor_id;"""
    conn = None
    vendor_id = None
    try:
        # read database configuration
        params = config()
        # connect to the PostgreSQL database
        conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
        # create a new cursor
        cur = conn.cursor()
        # execute the INSERT statement
        cur.execute(sql, (diagnosis,))
        # get the generated id back
        vendor_id = cur.fetchone()[0]
        # commit the changes to the database
        conn.commit()
        # close communication with the database
        cur.close()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()

    return vendor_id
```

The code above is not exactly right because it doesn't isolate the insert to the "diagnosis" field in the table.  But beyond that I also get the following error even though I did a successful pip install of config:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'config' from 'config' (/home/pinzhi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/config.py)
```

Thought on what I'm doing wrong or if there is a more straightforward way to insert a datapoint into a PostgreSql table I have?

EDIT ---------------------------------------------------------------------
The config error is no longer popping up after I followed the answer provided.  But my code above is unable to insert the diagnosis value of 3 into the table.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you running `pip install` _inside_ your script?

Comment: what is `config` module?

Comment: Why are you trying to `pip install` it at all? `config` is presumably a local file?

Comment: @roganjosh: where should I be running it?

Comment: `pip` is used to install libraries. Use it in a terminal/command prompt. Not in a script (i.e. through the python interpreter). But I can't understand the need to install it anyway (unless it's a library I don't know about), just import the file.

Comment: You INSERT rows, not strings.  If you want to add a string to an existing row, you need to UPDATE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's Config not config

```
from config import Config
params = Config()
```